# In VB.NET, writing AES key and encrypted data to same MemoryStream not working

Tags: vb.net, security, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I'm attempting to use symmetric encryption to encrypt some data, and store the key necessary to decrypt with the data in a MemoryStream. (While I know that this alone is really dumb security-wise, I'm going to use RSA to encrypt the symmetric key. Right now, though, I'm trying to just get this part to work.)

I'm using the FileHelpers library to parse the data for my delimiter (the semicolon, as I don't believe I'll ever have a semicolon in the data). Unfortunately, in my decryption function, when it's parsing, it only returns back one record. And, if I show the entire string of encrypted data created at the end of this function, it doesn't appear to be using multiple records.

I'm wondering if when I create the new cryptostream, it's defaulting to the beginning of the memory stream, so when I write my encrypted data, it overwrites the data I had just written to the memory stream. Do you think that's right?

Thanks for your help!

```
Private Function Encrypt(ByVal data As String) As String
    Dim utf8 As New UTF8Encoding
    ' Convert string data to byte array
    Dim inBytes() As Byte = utf8.GetBytes(data)
    ' Create memory stream for storing the data we've manipulated
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()

    Dim aes As New RijndaelManaged()
    aes.KeySize = 256

    Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    ' Write key to beginning of memory stream
    ms.Write(aes.Key, 0, aes.Key.Length)
    ' Add semicolon delimiter to memory stream
    ms.Write(utf8.GetBytes(";"), 0, utf8.GetBytes(";").Length)
    ' Write IV to memory stream
    ms.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length)
    ' Write semicolon delimiter to memory stream
    ms.Write(utf8.GetBytes(";"), 0, utf8.GetBytes(";").Length)
    ' Ensure that the data we've just written is in the memory stream, before
    ' we add the encrypted data
    ms.Flush()

    ' Write the encrypted data
    cs.Write(inBytes, 0, inBytes.Length) ' encrypt
    cs.FlushFinalBlock()

    ' Return encrypted data as string
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.Length)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick sample of how you can achieve this. I have included both the `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` because it is obviously important that you follow the same pattern on both sides. I will leave the relevant error checking etc. to you :)

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim encrypted As String = Encrypt("Here is the data")
    Dim decrypted As String = Decrypt(encrypted)
    Console.WriteLine(decrypted)
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub

  Private Function Encrypt(clearText As String) As String
    Dim aes As New RijndaelManaged
    aes.KeySize = 256

    Using ms As New MemoryStream
      ms.WriteByte(aes.Key.Length)
      ms.Write(aes.Key, 0, aes.Key.Length)
      ms.WriteByte(aes.IV.Length)
      ms.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length)

      Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        Dim bytes() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText)
        cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
      End Using

      Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
    End Using
  End Function

  Private Function Decrypt(cipherText As String) As String
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText))

    Dim keyLength As Byte = ms.ReadByte()
    Dim key(keyLength - 1) As Byte
    ms.Read(key, 0, keyLength)

    Dim ivLength As Byte = ms.ReadByte()
    Dim iv(ivLength - 1) As Byte
    ms.Read(iv, 0, ivLength)

    Dim dataOffset As Integer = ms.Position

    Dim aes As New RijndaelManaged()
    aes.Key = key
    aes.IV = iv

    Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
      Using sr As New StreamReader(cs, Encoding.UTF8)
        Return sr.ReadToEnd()
      End Using
    End Using
  End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing the the memory stream? Write directly to the Crypto stream then read the encrypted data back from the memory stream. Here is a C# version of AES encryption.

`aesEncryptor` is your `aes.CreateEncryptor()`

```
        private byte[] encryptWithAes(ICryptoTransform aesEncryptor, byte[] data)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = null; //stream to write encrypted data to
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = null; //crypto stream to encrypt data

            try
            {
                memStream = new MemoryStream(); 

                //initiate crypto stream telling it to write the encrypted data to the memory stream
                cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, aesEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                //write the data to the memory stream
                cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                //rethrow
                throw new Exception("Error while encrypting with AES: ", ee);
            }
            finally
            {
                //close 'em
                if (cryptoStream != null)
                    cryptoStream.Close();
                if (memStream != null)
                    memStream.Close();
            }

            //return the encrypted data
            return memStream.ToArray();
        }
```

this could be called as such:

```
public byte[] doEncrypt(byte[] dataToEncrypt)
{
            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
            aesAlg.KeySize = AES_KEY_SIZE;
            aesAlg.GenerateKey();
            aesAlg.GenerateIV();
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            byte[] aesKey = aesAlg.Key;
            byte[] aesIV = aesAlg.IV;

            byte[] encryptedData = encryptWithAes(aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(), dataToEncrypt);

            //store your aesKey, aesIV, and encryptedData together however you want
}
```

You shouldnt delemit binary data with any characters, becuase when you go to read that data back again you would have to encode the entire buffer, including the key and IV which, once encoded, could have your delimeter anywhere at random. Instead store the length of the key as a byte, then store the key after. When you go to read the data back, you can read the first byte (key length) as an integer, then know how much to read to get the key. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I was writing the key and IV to the memory stream, as I'm wanting to keep that so the data can be decrypted. My goal is to have the symmetrical key randomly generated each time, and the users then encrypt that with their RSA keys. Thus, I need to store the symmmetric key with the encrypted data.

Comment: @Sam, that memory stream should only be used by the crypto stream to write encrypted data to (and for you to read the encrypted data from). If you want to store the IV and key, use a different buffer, then append it to the encrypted data you read from the memory stream

Comment: @Sam, added an example of getting the IV, key, and encrypted data

Comment: @Petey Oh! I appear to be having a bad day searching the Internet, as I can't find an example of combining two memorystreams. Would I do this? Create a memorystream to hold the key and IV. Create a memorystream with cryptostream to hold the encrypted data. Create another memorystream, and then write the contents of the first memorystream, and then the second to it?

Comment: @Sam, why do you want to keep them in a memory stream? It is not a good idea to try and delimit with ';' in a memory stream (when you re-encode, to try and read the delimiter the encrypted data/key could have ';' anywhere). It would be better to store the first byte as the length of the key, then the key, then the next byte as the length of the IV, then the IV, then the rest would be the encrypted data.

Comment: @Petey What kind of var would I store that in? Sorry, I know I'm inept.

Comment: @Sam, you could store it all in a byte array, depending on how large the data/files you want to encrypt are. If they are too large to store in memory you will have to stream them to disk.